# Getting all the values of an array of Strings in one String

Tags: java, arrays, string

if I have,

```
String[] s = new String[3];
s[0] = "Ap";
s[1] = "p";
s[2] = "le";

String result = ?
```

If I want to get Apple out of s without looping, how do I do that?

Any short cut?

Answer (score 9):

If the not looping is more important to you than preventing to import another library or if you are using [apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) already, anyway, you can use the StringUtils.join method

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
String joined = StringUtils.join(s, "");
```

Maybe the Apache Commons have other methods that might be interesting for your project, as well. I found them to be a very useful resource for missing features in the native Java libraries.

Comment: Doesn't that just loop inside its implementation?

Comment: Obviously there's going to be a loop _somewhere!_

Comment: Yes it does check it out in the source http://kickjava.com/src/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.java.htm . But mainly I just want to emphasize the idea of using libraries. If that's the only function you will use it doesn't make sense to import the whole jar of course.

Comment: I also checked the source and saw that it used StringBuffer. Using StringBuilder will make it faster. But that is good answer. It points that "if you need something check java library, if it is not in there it must be in apache commons" :)

Answer (score 2):

Without looping, you can:

```
public String joinpart(String[] a, int i, String prefix) {
    if (i < a.length) {
        return joinpart(a, i + 1, prefix + a[i]);
    }
    return prefix;
}
```

then:

```
String[] a = new String[]{"Ap", "p", "le"};
String apple = joinpart(a, 0, "");
```

This is called a *recursive* solution.

Comment: It's also quadratic in the size of the resulting string. You should have used `StringBuilder` in `joinpart` to construct the string.

Comment: I don't think that's going to important for this particular learning exercise, so I didn't want to complicate the implementation. That would obscure the essence of the solution, which is what's important here.

Comment: Good solution. What about using a string builder? We could specify the capacity and append in a for loop instead of using recursive. I ask this because I think it would be faster for bigger size arrays. Am i wrong?

Comment: @jcasso: The question asked for a solution "without looping". I mentioned the use of StringBuilder in my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the length of your array, you can easily do the following:

```
String result = s[0] + s[1] +s[2];
```

Another option is to do the following, (which is purely academic, I would not use it in a real-world scenario as it would remove `[`, `]`, and `<space>` from your strings):

```
String result = Arrays.toString(s).replaceAll("[\\]\\[, ]", "");
```

Yet another option, to go along with the first attempt, but using a C-like formatter:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%s%s%s", s));
```

Comment: If the length is 100? You need a loop.

Answer (score 1):

using [Dollar](http://bitbucket.org/dfa/dollar) is simple as typing:

```
String[] array = new String[] { "Ap", "p", "le" };
String result = $(array).join(); // result now is "Apple"
```

Comment: But the question is about Java, not Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = s[0] + s[1] + s[2];
```

If you have an unknown number of entries, I think you'll need a loop.

Comment: I think he just gave an example. What if the array is passed in a method?

Comment: Well the array knows how big it is (in Java, anyway), and then you can loop.  Otherwise, tough luck.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have a `String.join()` type method. You'll have to roll one yourself if you want to hide the loop.